# Excel: Calculate duration hh:mm:ss based on a separate column

Tags: excel

I have two columns with different data, I need to calculate the duration in hh:mm:ss based on the data in column A, (example below), at the moment I'm having to do this manually using filters, is there an easier way?

```
A   B
2   00:00:04
2   00:00:07
4   00:06:23
4   00:02:07
1   00:07:07
1   00:01:08

total of 2 would equal 00:00:11
total of 4 would equal 00:08:30
total of 2 would equal 00:08:15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the SUMIF function:

```
=SUMIF(A2:A7, 2, B2:B7)
```

This sums the values in `B2:B7` where the corresponding value in `A2:A7` is equal to the middle parameter, 2.

Comment: Thanks David that works a treat, is it possible to use a wildcard for the middle parameter